# MKMapView add annotation and remove it after some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkpointannotation

I have a MKMapView and I add some annotations to it. I want to remove annotations one by one after some time that it was added. I need that every annotation have its own lifespan. Is it possible? How should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best choice is to use `-(void)removeAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations` from your `MKMapView`.

Just save your annotation somewhere, for example a NSDictionary with {date : annotationObject}, and retrieve it when you want to delete.

For example:

```
//Call somewhere to delete after 2 seconds
[self performSelector:@selector(deleteAnnotation:) withObject:annotation afterDelay:2.f]

//this function will remove the annotation from your map
-(void) deleteAnnotation:(id) object{
    [self.map removeAnnotations:@[object]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MKMapView has `removeAnnotation` and `removeAnnotations` methods which remove already added annotations.

If you want each annotation to have their own lifespan :

- Create `AnnotationLifespanDelegate` protocol with method for indicating end of life which takes the annotation as a parameter (e.g. `func dearAnnotationRIP(annotation : MKAnnotation)`).
- Create a custom MKAnnotation with the `lifespan` and `lifeSpanDelegate` properties and a `startCountdown` method.
- `startCountdown` method simply starts a timer with with an interval equal to the `lifespan` and calls the end of life method on the delegate.
- Implement `AnnotationLifespanDelegate` methods in view controller and while creating annotation objects,  make sure you set the `lifespan` and the `delegate` and call the `startCountdown` method on the annotation immediately after you add it to the map view.
- In the annotation end of life method, remove annotation from the map.